# Tensorflow: How to get the value of the k-th diagonal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, diagonal

In PyTorch, the function `torch.diag()` gets the value of the k-th diagonal of a tensor.

For example, `a.diag(diagonal=1)` gets the value of the 1-th diagonal. Unfortunately `diag_part()` doesn't appear to work in Tensorflow:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
a.diag(diagonal=1)
tensor([2, 6])
a.diag(diagonal=2)
tensor([3])
```

Is there an equivalent function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TensorFlow 2 >= v2.2**

You can use [`tf.linalg.diag_part`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/diag_part)

```
>>> a = tf.reshape(tf.range(1,10),(3,3))
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>
>>> tf.linalg.diag_part(a,k=1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 6], dtype=int32)>
>>> tf.linalg.diag_part(a,k=2)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([3], dtype=int32)>
```

**TensorFlow 1.x and TensorFlow 2 <= v2.1**

**2020-11-26:** As of tf 1.15 and tf2.1, The code in `tf.linalg.diag_part` to produce superdiagonals and subdiagonals seems to be disabled. You can use directly `matrix_diag_part_v2` to get the desired behaviour as a workaround :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_array_ops import matrix_diag_part_v2

a = tf.reshape(tf.range(1,10),(3,3))
superdiag = matrix_diag_part_v2(a,k=1,padding_value=0)
superdiag2 = matrix_diag_part_v2(a,k=2,padding_value=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(f"Matrix A : {sess.run(a)}")
    print(f"Superdiagonal 1 : {sess.run(superdiag)}")
    print(f"Superdiagonal 2 : {sess.run(superdiag2)}")
```

Results in

```
Matrix A : [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
Superdiagonal 1 : [2 6]
Superdiagonal 2 : [3]
```

---

**2021-01-08**: The bug in tf 1.15 is not high priority and a fix is not planned. [Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45203#issuecomment-740016390) :

> Yes. This is clearly a bug in 1.15. But It's definitely not something significant enough that we'd make a patch release for it, we only do patch releases for major bugs or security fixes.

**2021-01-08**: Thanks to Krzysztof to point out that the same issue found in TF1 arises for TF versions <= 2.1. The `matrix_diag_part_v2` workaround works also for TF2.1 and TF2.0.